# superimpose an image over another image with python

Tags: python, image

Is there a built in function that allows an image to be added over another image in python? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Use the `blend` function from the Image module: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Answer (score 3):

[`Image.paste()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) from [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) will do that.