# Superimposing text and an image onto another image

Tags: python

I have a template image on top of which I'd like to superimpose a variety of other images and texts. In my head it's as simple as loading the template image, and then processing a CSV for the text and a folder for the superimposed images. Are there good ways to do this via python?

Both packages suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755867/superimpose-an-image-over-another-image-with-python) are defunct.

Comment: The `PIL` package recommended in that answer has been superseded by `Pillow`.

Comment: Here's something similar with **ImageMagick** https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115925/2836621

Comment: With PIL https://stackoverflow.com/a/62427301/2836621

Comment: See also Github link in comments under this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71201007/2836621